# Don't understand how variables work inside __init__.py

Tags: python, package, global-variables

First of all, I have a variable and function inside `__init__.py` file:

```
dbname = 'dbname'
def crud(_dbname):
    global dbname
    dbname = _dbname
    print(dbname) # the value here is correct

    from . import edit
    edit.render()
```

Inside the `edit.py`, I `print(dbname)`

```
from . import *

def render():
    print(dbname) # wrong value
```

Then I call to this package method in each url from other files:

```
from .crud import crud
@admin.route('/user/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def adminuser():
   crud('user')

from .crud import crud
@admin.route('/group/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def admingroup():
   crud('group')
```

It always prints `user`? Or if I print dbname inside `crud` method and `edit.py` file, they print different values.

`dbname` has been updated in crud but couldn't see the new value in edit.py file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I can't understand you well as your explanation is really confusing. I guess you are printing `dbname` in this way:

```
# edit.py
from xxx import dbname

print(dbname)
crud(another_value)
print(dbname)
```

And then you find you get the same values. That is because when you `from xxx import dbname`, you get a local copy of original `dbname`. To get the original `dbname`, you need to use `sys.modules["xxx"].dbname`.

Comment: It breaks my design pattern. Follow my question, put the variable inside `__init__.py` , change its value and didn't work.

Comment: As I have said, `print(dbname)` inside `__init__.py` prints what you want, but `print(dbname)` inside `edit.py` prints a local copy of original `dbname` which is made by `from . import *`. You may be wondering why it prints `user` but not default value `dbname`? It seems it has been changed but only once? That is because `edit.py` is executed when it comes to `from . import edit` and local copy was created at this moment. The time you call `crud('user')` is the first time you call `crud`. If you try to access `/group/` first, you will find it always print out `group` instead of `user`.

Comment: Thank for your explaination. But when the local copy was created? After open the url `/group` , the `dbname` value must be updated to `group` why it is `user`, while the page is refreshed, `dbname` must be updated, right?. Why python still keep `dbname` old value in the memory? I'm working with PHP and really feel strange with this concept. Then how do i get `dbname` updated to correct value everytime i execute different urls?

Comment: Local copy was created at the first time you import `edit.py`. To get original `dbname`, you should add a function `def get_dbname(): return dbname` into `__init__.py`. And get `dbname` by this function.

Comment: Thank you. I changed to use class inside `__init__.py`. Do you have any document about how python works with package variables or import command? Ive been searching for it to understand when local copy was created, when it use variable value like this case?